# Is there a Perl module to monitor an email queue?

Tags: perl, email, exchange-server, cpan

I'm working on an issue tracking system and would like the application to handle email replies.  That is, I would like a script that can monitor an email queue and perform some action based on the email contents.  It should then be able to delete the email, etc.

I currently use MIME::Lite to send email, and I can handle writing the script etc. (read: I'm not new to Perl).  However, I have no idea what modules are good for doing this particular task.  I'd like to get started on this as quickly as possible so I hope to narrow my search space for possible modules.

In case you need to know, the application will be running on a standard linux, Perl, MySQL stack with Exchange as the mail server.

Can anyone suggest a Perl module to help me out?  Any tutorials or best practices related to this would also be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have access to the [Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Exchange_Server) server via [IMAP](http://IMAP) or [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webdav)?

For IMAP:

- [Mail::IMAPClient](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mail::IMAPClient)
- [IMAP::Client](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IMAP::Client)
- [Net::IMAP::Client](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net::IMAP::Client)
- [Email::Folder::IMAP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Folder::IMAP)

For WebDAV:

- [Email::Folder::Exchange](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Folder::Exchange)

POP3 would also be an option if it's enabled on the server.  IMAP is probably the way to go if you've got it.

Comment: That's kind of interesting... it uses the web access site.  Have you used this in an application?

Comment: I have access to pop, imap, and webdav.  I would think IMAP or WebDAV are the better protocols.  Any preference?

Comment: IMAP is much faster than WebDAV, so I'd advise you to go with that.

Answer (score 3):

I've done something similar using [Mail::POP3Client](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mail::POP3Client)

Answer (score 1):

The Perl Email Project @ http://emailproject.perl.org/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page has recommendations and other information on the mail oriented modules for perl.

Comment: I did try out the Email::* modules updated by this group and found the one I needed (Email::Folder::IMAP) to have a bug that caused it to die when connecting.  I also found the API to be very inconsistent between connection types.  Net::IMAP::Client has a similar, simple API but is more mature.