# What is the simplest way to run a script when an email is received?

Tags: mysql, email, iis-7, exchange-server, pipe

I'd like to run a script, typically in PHP or MySQL since it involves changing a Mysql db table when an email arrives at my exchange server (2010).

The server holds IIS7.

So in short:
Email->Exchange server->changes a table in MySQL DB

Notes:

- Not looking for a script that connects to the e-mail via POP/imap
- I'm looking for a kind of trigger that occurs in the server
- Webservices or Transport Agent seem complicated If you can supply an easy example I'll accept it.
- If you have a Sink example that runs on Exchange 2010 please support it with careful explanation and examples/links. (step by step if you have to)
- Other scripting languages accepted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091746/exchange-2010-run-command-on-mail-receive

Comment: Too bad you are not running this on a Linux server:
http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-script/

Comment: @MarcB Not useful :( scanning inbox is inneficient and EWS (web services) is not an option. Thanks

Comment: MySQL part still applies and is very important since It should be triggered by any script and I don't know how to run a MySQL command via other scripts

Comment: @mti2935 Actually your suggestion has been the best so far! I've figured out how to replace **#!/usr/bin/php -q** on the script by windows version (basically just writting the php.exe path followed by -q, without #!). All I need now is a way to pipe the email. My problem is email and php servers are not the same :S

Comment: @JDuarteDJ I deleted my answer since the info doesn't apply to this version. But the link in your comment was useful, so I'm reproducing it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674329/running-script-on-exchange-2010

Comment: You coulf go for a solution using PERL (which runs on windows). Check the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/q/710304/2432317

Comment: @e-sushi Not really what I'm looking for since those script fetch the email after it arrived at the served, I want to process the email on arrival as if I was the server, If I choose to discard an email it will never exist, and unless I process it it will go to "email limbo", or nowhere!

Comment: From your comment on 7/26, it sounds like you're close.  I take it that installing php on the mail server is not an option.  So, instead of piping the incoming messages to a PHP script, how about piping them to a Powershell script?

Comment: @mti2935 exploring possibilities, but that might be it.

Comment: @mti2935 could you please make your first comment into an answer? It might be the closest match to the answer I'm looking for AND I've a bounty to award!

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not exactly what you are looking for but [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com) offer an incoming mail service that allows you to do this kind of thing.

Their API is pretty good and very well [documented](http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-inbound-webhook.html). My understanding is you can set up webhooks that will allow you to do what you're looking for.

I hope this is some use to you.

Comment: It sounds like a good piece of SaaS but it is pay per use and altough it wasn't specified it wasn't my goal, my goal was to implement using our resources (or a free service), I was able to find a google apps engine solution to this problem but since our mail is now  Google it doesn't answer this particular question. Also for Gmail users I think there is a GMail API that may help with this :)